# Chanakya font - few characters are not rendering

Tags: fonts, truetype, hindi, indic

I have a MS Word doc which uses Chanakya font, after installing Chanakya font, instead of half ka क् example क्या, I am getting `€(EURO) symbol`. Below are few sample screenshots:

- [image]
- [image]
- [image]
- [image]
- [image]

Chanakya font version can be viewed in the screenshot below:
[image]

These documents source are unknown and we can't identify if there was an earlier version of Chanakya font being used. I can think of the following:

- Is there a possibility to identify the font version used in source doc files?
- Any alternate way to fix this issue?

I have tried downloading PFB file of Chanakya font from `https://sites.google.com/site/technicalhindi/about/_draft_post` and then converted it to TTF using an online PFB to TTF Converter, but no success.

Sample MS Word document link for reference:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oioblxos9twb3q2/sample%20chanakya%20doc.doc?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, but have you ruled out encoding issues? If you copy the text into a web browser, does it show as the correct Indic text, or does it have the same issues?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and it doesn't show right Indic text.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the full text here? Maybe that'll be insightful.

Comment: çÂÀUÜð çÎÙæð´ ×æðÙðÅU ·¤×ü¿æÚUè ·ð¤ ƒæÚU ƒæéâ·¤ÚU ÁæÙÜðßæ ãU×Üæ ·¤ÚUÙð ·ð¤ ×æ×Üð ×ð´ ÂéçÜâ Ùð Îæð Üæð»æð´ ·¤æð ç»ÚUÌæÚU ç·¤Øæ ãñUÐ ÎæðÙæð´ ¥æÚUæðçÂØæð´ ·¤æð çÚU×æ´ÇU ÂÚU ÁðÜ ÖðÁæ »Øæ ãñUÐ
It is rendered like that

Comment: i have the same issue. some characters have problems